# Where Clause with Equality and Like Condition RoR 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Can I have a statement like this in RoR 4:

```
@vendors = Vendor.includes(:business).where(:business_id=>@business.id,:city_id=>city,:activated=>"1",["business.business_name LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%"]).page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

If not, then how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do that, but you **can** chain `.where()` calls together, ie.

```
.where(business_id: @business.id).where("businesses.business_name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Note that you will need to includes `.references(:business)` in order to ensure that the `LEFT JOIN` is performed:

```
Vendor.includes(:business).references(:business).where(business_id:@business.id, etc..).where('businesses.business_name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Comment: Something like this?:
`@vendors = Vendor.includes(:business).where(:business_id=>@business.id,:city_id=>city,:activated=>"1").where("business.business_name LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)`

Comment: I tried but it is giving me this error:

`Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'business.business_name' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `vendors`  WHERE `vendors`.`business_id` = 5 AND `vendors`.`city_id` = 1 AND `vendors`.`activated` = '1' AND (business.business_name LIKE '%abc%')`

Comment: This does work but it is without like clause which I need:
`@vendors = Vendor.includes(:business).where(:business_id=>@business.id,:city_id=>city,:activated=>"1","business.business_name"=>params[:search]).page(params[:page]).per_page(10)`

Comment: If it's without the clause you need, then it's wrong to say that it does work. The other one probably isn't working because your table name is probably pluralized, ie. you need to have `businesses.business_name` in your string. I assumed that you already had those names correct.

Comment: The error is in views when I am trying to paginate or call @vendors.count

Comment: No, that's not true, you pasted the SQL error and it shows "business.business_name". However, I can also see that the `includes` didn't do an `OUTER JOIN`, so add a `.references(:business)` (I've updated my answer).

Comment: As I mentioned in the update to my answer, it forces the `LEFT JOIN` to happen, otherwise Rails will only do a `LEFT JOIN` if it sees a reference to the `includes` table, which it can't see when you provide string arguments.